# Custom View not drawing

Tags: android, canvas, view

i'm gonna try to draw a simple arc on my custom view, but it just won't show anything. It has been bothering me for a long time.

It's the main actitvity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  //setContentView(new Ring(this));

}}
```

And it's the main xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ring="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.shockwave.arandomer"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.shockwave.arandomer.Ring 
                android:id="@+id/ring"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ring:ring_color="red"
                ring:stroke_width="5.0"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Then this is the main class handle the drawing:

```
public class Ring extends ViewGroup{
Paint paint = null;
float stroke_w;
int ring_color;

public Ring(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context,attrs);
    setFocusable(true);



    TypedArray type = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.Ring,0,0);
    try{
        stroke_w = type.getFloat(R.styleable.Ring_stroke_width, (float)3.0);
        ring_color = type.getInteger(R.styleable.Ring_ring_color, 0);//default: black
    }finally{
        type.recycle();
    }

    switch(ring_color){
    case 0:
        ring_color = Color.BLACK;
        break;
    case 1:
        ring_color = Color.RED;
        break;
    case 2:
        ring_color = Color.GREEN;
        break;
    }

    Ring_main ring_view = new Ring_main(getContext());
    addView(ring_view);

    //ring_view.invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);

}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){

    int minw = getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight() + getSuggestedMinimumWidth();
   int w = Math.max(minw, MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec));

   int minh = getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom() + getSuggestedMinimumHeight();
   int h = Math.max(MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec), minh);



   setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh){
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
}

private class Ring_main extends View{

    public Ring_main(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Ring_main(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);



        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(ring_color);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(stroke_w);
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

        RectF oval = new RectF();
        oval.set(100, 100, 300, 300);
        canvas.drawArc(oval, 90, 180, false, paint);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html follow this tut

Comment: why do you. need Ring class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner class `Ring_main` doesn't override `onMeasure` so it is going to have zero height and width.

Your outer class `Ring` doesn't do anything in `onLayout` and tell the children where they should be drawn on the screen, so that will also cause issues. Nine times out of ten, you are going to want to subclass LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, or FrameLayout, rather than ViewGroup, so you don't have to override `onMeasure` and `onLayout`.

But is there any reason for you to be using a view group for this when there is only one child view? It seems like you could move the `onDraw` method into the parent `Ring`, delete the inner `Ring_main` class, and change `Ring` to subclass View, and you'd be mostly done.

**Edit:**
In response to your code in the comment below:
Your `onMeasure` implementation is wrong, because you ignore the possible mode attached to the incoming width and height. For example, in your layout xml, the parent has a height of `wrap_content` so the `onMeasure`'s height parameter is going to to have a mode of `UNSPECIFIED` and when you call `MeasureSpec.getSize(aHeight)` it will return a useless number (although it seems to default to zero).

This is a more correct implementation, although ultimately, there are more details you will need to consider, such as whether you want the arc to expand to fill whatever amount of space is available to your view, or to always be the same size and just center itself in the view.

```
static final float DESIRED_WIDTH_BEFORE_PADDING = 100;
static final float DESIRED_HEIGHT_BEFORE_PADDING = 200;

protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

   int wDesired = getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight() + 
       Math.max(DESIRED_WIDTH_BEFORE_PADDING, getSuggestedMinimumWidth());
   int wSpecMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
   int w = 0;
   switch(wSpecMode){
       case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
           w = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
           break;
       case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
           w = Math.min(wDesired, MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec));
           break;
       case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
           w = wDesired;
           break;
   }

   int hDesired = getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom() + 
       Math.max(DESIRED_HEIGHT_BEFORE_PADDING, getSuggestedMinimumHeight());
   int hSpecMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
   int h = 0;
   switch(hSpecMode){
       case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
           h = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
           break;
       case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
           h = Math.min(hDesired, MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec));
           break;
       case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
           h = hDesired;
           break;
   }

   setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
}
```

If your min SDK is 11 or higher, this can be simplified a lot with the `resolveSizeAndState` method.

Note the above is simplified to ignore DIP. Those two static floats should be in DIP units, and then multiply them by density when you use them in `onMeasure`.

It will also be up to you to override `onSizeChanged` to calculate what actual height and width you will use to draw your arc, as well as any offsets required to possibly center the arc within the view. Then these values would be used in `onDraw` to ensure the arc draws where you want it to.

Comment: Than i found that the height it measure will always be 0.As a consequence, it wouldn't enter onDraw

Comment: But if i force to give method setMeasuredDimension a set of height and width, it would enter onDraw. But still, nothing would be drew!!

Comment: See edit -- your onMeasure implementation is incorrect.